# Emacs mode in zsh: M-b M-f etc. show weird symbols

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, xterm

I have set up zsh to use emacs mode. But typing <kbd>Alt+f</kbd> or <kbd>Alt+b</kbd> inserts weird symbols (accented letters and so on), rather than moving around by word in the shell like it should. Since I don't ever want to insert the "ae" symbol into a shell prompt, how can I get zsh to behave?

I had the same problem with bash, but now that I'm actually taking the time to customise zsh, I thought I'd ask...

<kbd>AltGr+b</kbd> etc. produces *different* weird symbols...

I'm using Ubuntu 10.4

Comment: Are you using `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: xterm, I believe. Is that the same thing?

Comment: no `xterm` is a program (which practically ships as part of xorg), so is `gnome-terminal`. `gnome-terminal` is an X Terminal however, and that's often abbreviated as *xterm*. Just to clarify any confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not zsh that's misbehaving, it's xterm. The reason it's misbehaving is an obsolete setting that causes xterm to send character number *x*+128 when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd> together with character number *x*. The normal behavior in a text terminal is to have <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> send `ESC a`.

To tell xterm to leave 8-bit characters alone, turn off the `XTerm.VT100.eightBitInput` resource (despite the name, it doesn't affect what happens when you enter an 8-bit character). You'd normally do this by adding the following line to `~/.Xresources`:

```
XTerm.VT100.eightBitInput:      false
```

`~/.Xresources` is read when you log in in most unix distributions. To read it immediately, run the command

```
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
```